# How Can I create complicated query in just one query like working with MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access in order to summary stuffs.
As an example, assuming that I had these 3 queries below

**1. fetching all males who are aged over 20**

```
1. select users.id, users.name, users.age, users.gender 
   from users
   where users.age > 20 AND users.gender = 1   (means male)
```

**2. fetching all cars whose make is "FORD"**

```
2. select cars.user_id, cars.make, cars.name_of_car
   from cars
   where cars.make = "FORD"
```

**3. fecthing all accidents that are the most recent happened in 2014**

```
3. select accidents.user_id, accidents.car_accident_date_ymd
   from accidents
   group by accidents.user_id
   having (((max(accidents.car_accident_date_ymd)) Like "2014*"));
```

At 4th query, I connect them all together

```
users.id(1) = (n)cars.user_id
users.id(1) = (1)accidents.user_id
```

then show

```
`users.id, users.name, users.age, users.gender, cars.make, accidents.car_accident_date_ymd`
```

How can I put them all together in one query?
If possible, I'd like to use all 3 queries above and put them together somehow.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select users.id, users.name, users.age, 
users.gender, cars.make, max(accidents.car_accident_date_ymd)
from accidents 
join users on users.id = accidents.user_id
join cars on cars.user_id = users.id
where users.age > 20 
    and users.gender = 1 
    and cars.make = 'FORD'
group by users.id, users.name, users.age, 
users.gender, cars.make
having max(accidents.car_accident_date_ymd) Like "2014*"
```

The query above assumes you want to select the most recent `car_accident_date_ymd`, if you want to select every unique one you'll need to include it in your `group by` which means you might get duplicate users in your result set i.e.

```
select users.id, users.name, users.age, 
users.gender, cars.make, accidents.car_accident_date_ymd
from accidents 
join users on users.id = accidents.user_id
join cars on cars.user_id = users.id
where users.age > 20 
    and users.gender = 1 
    and cars.make = 'FORD'
group by users.id, users.name, users.age, 
users.gender, cars.make, accidents.car_accident_date_ymd
having max(accidents.car_accident_date_ymd) Like "2014*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to `JOIN`:

```
SELECT users.id, 
       users.name, 
       users.age, 
       users.gender, 
       cars.make, 
       accidents.car_accident_date_ymd 
FROM   users users 
       JOIN cars cars 
         ON users.id = cars.user_id 
       JOIN accidents accidents 
         ON accidents.user_id = users.id 
WHERE  users.age > 20 
       AND users.gender = 1 
       AND cars.make = "ford" 
GROUP  BY accidents.user_id 
HAVING (( ( Max(accidents.car_accident_date_ymd) ) LIKE "2014*" ));
```